# Update a data extension based on the records of another data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I have synchronized the Leads created in Salesforce with a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud.

I want to update the value of my DE `doctors` attribute `isRegistered` to `Y`, if I find a record in my synchronized DE which has a common record to the DE `doctors`.

I consider the records to be common if both have same `email id`.

Edit:-
I tried to filter the synchronized DE on Automation studio, but I am unable to see any record on the journey builder. Furthermore, I tried to manually create a filtered DE and then add it to the Journey Builder, but the Journey Builder doesn't reflect any update I make to my DE after it (the Journey Builder) is started.

Comment: Have you started writing the query?  If so, can you update your question to include what you have?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
select
/* add required Lead columns here */
, 'Y' as isRegistered
from Lead_Salesforce as l
inner join doctors as d on (d.[email id] = l.[email id])
```

The `inner join` ensures only those `Lead_Salesforce` rows with a matching `doctor` row are updated.

Comment: But Adam how can I make sure that the update takes place on demand or atleast follows a regular schedule.